# How to analyze windows 7 bsod error minidump?

Tags: windows, windows-7, crash, driver, crash-reports

I got blue screen of death (bsod) error on my laptop some time ago. I read online that analyzing minidump file in "c:\windows\minidump" will help understand cause behind bsod error. (and probably point to the culprit driver causing the error)

I used this online tool to analyze error http://www.osronline.com/page.cfm?name=analyze

It created a report but I do not understand it. If you can understand it, please let me know.

Link to online crash analysis report: https://pastebin.com/raw/3Hhq7arw

Dump file location: https://drive.google.com/file/d/0BzNdoGke8tyRZk5YcHBKQV8ycFE/view?usp=sharing

Laptop config: Windows 7, 32 bit

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You get an [WHEA_UNCORRECTABLE_ERROR (124) Bugcheck](https://msdn.microsoft.com/de-de/library/windows/hardware/ff557321(v=vs.85).aspx), which measn there is a fatal hardware error:

> The WHEA_UNCORRECTABLE_ERROR bug check has a value of 0x00000124. This
>   bug check indicates that a fatal hardware error has occurred.

Using the `!errrec` command in Windbg and the value from parameter 2 I see you have an Internal timer issue with your Intel i3-3217U CPU:

```
===============================================================================
Common Platform Error Record @ 8a0a401c
-------------------------------------------------------------------------------
Record Id     : 01d1ff7437bf4c24
Severity      : Fatal (1)
Length        : 928
Creator       : Microsoft
Notify Type   : Machine Check Exception
Timestamp     : 8/26/2016 8:32:29 (UTC)
Flags         : 0x00000000

===============================================================================
Section 0     : Processor Generic
-------------------------------------------------------------------------------
Descriptor    @ 8a0a409c
Section       @ 8a0a4174
Offset        : 344
Length        : 192
Flags         : 0x00000001 Primary
Severity      : Fatal

Proc. Type    : x86/x64
Instr. Set    : x86
Error Type    : Micro-Architectural Error
Flags         : 0x00
CPU Version   : 0x00000000000306a9
Processor ID  : 0x0000000000000003

===============================================================================
Section 1     : x86/x64 Processor Specific
-------------------------------------------------------------------------------
Descriptor    @ 8a0a40e4
Section       @ 8a0a4234
Offset        : 536
Length        : 128
Flags         : 0x00000000
Severity      : Fatal

Local APIC Id : 0x0000000000000003
CPU Id        : a9 06 03 00 00 08 10 03 - bf e3 ba 3d ff fb eb bf
                00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 - 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00
                00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 - 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00

Proc. Info 0  @ 8a0a4234

===============================================================================
Section 2     : x86/x64 MCA
-------------------------------------------------------------------------------
Descriptor    @ 8a0a412c
Section       @ 8a0a42b4
Offset        : 664
Length        : 264
Flags         : 0x00000000
Severity      : Fatal

Error         : Internal timer (Proc 3 Bank 3)
  Status      : 0xbe00000000800400
  Address     : 0x0000000085286f3c
  Misc.       : 0x0000000000000000
```

I see that you use the ASUS X550CA Laptop:

```
BiosVersion = X550CA.217
BiosReleaseDate = 01/23/2014
SystemManufacturer = ASUSTeK COMPUTER INC.
SystemProductName = X550CA
```

I see you se the older BIOS Version .217, so [update the BIOS to .300](https://www.asus.com/de/supportonly/X550CA/HelpDesk_download), maybe it fixes the issue. If this doesn't fix the issue, do a stress test of the CPU with Prime95 and [Intel CPU Diag tool](https://downloadcenter.intel.com/download/19792/Intel-Processor-Diagnostic-Tool).